# How to add score to scoreboard?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I am making a simple game, it is my first project with JavaScript. So You click the button, it gives You and Computer a math randoms, the winner is the one with bigger number. I created a scoreboard and want to add score whetever someone wins.  The problem is that it doesnt work, could You please give me some solutions?

My HTML code:

```
   <html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Random - the game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <center><h1>Random</h1>
    <h2>The Game</h2></center></center>
  </header>
  <div class = "scoreTable">
    <span id="userScore">0</span>
    <span>:</span>
    <span id="compScore">0</span>
  </div>
  <div id="button">
    <center><img id="buttonOff" src="images/buttonOff.png" alt="przycisk" height="150px" width="150px" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" onclick="randomNumUser(); randomNumComp(); addScore()" /><center>
  </div>
  <center><div id="message1">
    <p>Your number</p>
    <p class="number" id="userNumber"></p>
  </div></center>
  <center><div id="message2">
    <p>Computer number</p>
    <p class="number" id="computerNumber"></p>
  </div></center>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS function for adding score:

```
 function addScore() {
  let userResult = Number(document.getElementById("userNumber"));
  let compResult = Number(document.getElementById("computerNumber"));
  let userScore = Number(document.getElementById("userScore"));
  let computerScore = Number(document.getElementById("compScore"));
  if (userResult > compResult) {
    userScore = userScore.innerHTML =+ 1;
  } else if (userResult < compResult) {
    computerScore = computerScore.innerHTML =+ 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that those element are inputs, you need to grab their `.value`. The first order of debugging is to console.log() or alert() stuff to make sure it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: and operating under the same assumption you'd then want to write that value back into the HTML element after you calculated the result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "value" of this DOM Element. updated code is here

```
 function addScore() {
   let userResult = document.getElementById("userNumber");
   let compResult = document.getElementById("computerNumber");
   let userScore = document.getElementById("userScore");
   let computerScore = document.getElementById("compScore");
   if (Number(userResult.innerText) > Number(compResult.innerText)) {
     userScore.innerText = Number(userScore.innerText) + 1;
   } else if (Number(userResult.innerText) < Number(compResult.innerText)) {
   computerScore.innerText = Number(computerScore.innerText) + 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I am waiting, really thank You, because that one which You had written is not working :(

Comment: Please check the updated code. it should work for you :)

Comment: can you please post your code to codepen or some online editor, so that i can debug and fix it for you :)